# Python Files help needed

Tags: python, python-3.x

my program works fine checking the file with periodic table number and elements with this program:

```
userline=input('Enter element number or element name: ')
userline=userline.capitalize()
f=open('periodic_table.txt')
while userline:
 for line in f:
   number,element=line.split()
```

but if i add to the program like this:

```
   else:
     print('Thats not an element!')
     userline=input('Enter element number or element name: ')
     userline=userline.capitalize()
```

it keep printing that not an element even if we put correct number of element or correct name,

Comment: try using a debugger - insert `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` after the input statments and step through the code to see what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your current approach isn't working is because you're iterating through a list. If you do `userline != element`, the very first time you encounter an element or number that isn't equal to the user input, the program will print the error message. Since you're looping through every periodic table element, you're going to get a bunch of error messages!

Instead, try first adding each periodic table element and number into a dictionary or list. That way, you can check if what the user typed in is inside the dictionary, and return an error message without having to loop through the entire thing.

Here's a short example of what you might want to try instead:

```
# The "with" statement automatically closes the file for you!
with open('periodic_table.txt') as f:  
    numbers = {}
    elements = {}
    for line in f:
        num, element = line.split()
        numbers[num] = element
        elements[element] = num

while True:
    userline = input('Enter element number or element name: ')
    userline = userline.capitalize()

    if userline in numbers:
        print('Element number ' + userline + ' is ' + numbers[userline])
    elif userline in elements:
        print('Element number for ' + userline + ' is ' + elements[userline])
    else:
        print("That's not real!")
```

(Caveat: I didn't try running this, so you might have to tweak it a bit to make sure it works properly)

Comment: still then i want to end the loop when user enter blank, so when i take the input above the while again the same error, print nothing but taking input again n again

Comment: @MystIcAce -- try modifying the "if" statement so that you check if `userline == ""` (if it equals the empty string). If it is, then use the `break` keyword to end the `while` loop.